# Why was my question about not being able to boot from USB poorly received?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[PC does not start from Windows 10 USB](https://superuser.com/questions/1391569/pc-does-not-start-from-windows-10-usb)

It got downvotes almost instantly. I would like to understand why? Maybe I can improve my question.

I asked it because I kind of feel stuck in my quest to make the laptop usable again. I do not understand why is it not able to boot from a Windows 10 USB while still being able to boot from a Linux Mint USB! This perplexes me.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted, but it might be because the question is a bit disorganised. I suggest editing it to concentrate on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Blackwood I tried rewriting my Q; is it OK now?

Comment: Explaining a single downvote is guesswork.  The current version seems pretty clear, but it's missing detail and diagnostic information that would allow a definitive solution.  Just to manage expectations, it's tough to diagnose a problem that can have a range of causes in a Q&A format.  It's even tougher if you lack familiarity with the relevant tools and technical details.  Some problems are a lot easier to solve if you enlist the help of a knowledgeable friend.  Short of that, you can do a lot of online research to try to get up to speed on the issue.  (cont'd)

Comment: It can also be more effective to use a forum than a Q&A site.  That format is more conducive to a lot of interactive discussion, which is often the key to figuring out the problem.

Comment: MKUSB is the only tool that works with the new Microsoft ISOs. I've tested it successfully and posted an answer to your question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Votes are like a jury trial, 11 may think you are not guilty of anything, but 1 just wants to hang you. I agree, newer users see down votes as something negative, but in reality someone will come along and vote it back up. Being impatient here at SU should be avoided by everyone.